# AucTeX TOC with multifile document

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex, r

I'm writing my PhD thesis with LaTeX-Sweave and I use EMACS with AucTex and ESS. I have a master file (master.tex) and some slave files and my question is about the use of the TOC in the slave files. What should I do to see the TOC on the slave files? Because when I pres C-c= I see only an empty TOC.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the AuCTeX manual, it has a section called 'Multifile documents'. Try typing `C-c _` in each of the slave documents and set the master file to your master file.

Comment: I have just read both reftex and auctex manuals but I havent found an answare to my problem. I have alrady settede the master file (**C-c_**)

Comment: Strange, that's all I do to make it work with my multifile documents. Make sure there's a line like `%%% TeX-master: "master"` at the end of each subdocument.